# How to install Ubuntu on Macbook Pro 10.8.5

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, macbook-pro, usb-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and need help downloading Ubuntu onto my Macbook Pro 10.8.5.
I'll eventually need it to run ROS. I've looked through numerous documentations on what to install, but am still so lost...I've installed VirtualBox. Could someone please help me? D:

Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

here's how to boot from usb : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick 
If you are wanting to make a Dual-Boot or replace the mac os with ubuntu this link explane
everything : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro10-1/Precise 
If you are wanting to install it on Virtual Machine  
 here's a youtube video 
 
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_42JLz2izBU